# Is there any way to pass AND and OR conditions in linux cp command

Tags: linux, cp

I want to copy jar and war files present inside a directory to destination
The condition here is if there are no jar present inside dir it should copy only war's and vice versa
Any suggestions on how this can be done using cp command?
Thank you

Comment: At least on git bash ends with error but does it's job `cp *.jar *.war`

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply 
Yes it does its job but I am integrating this in a pipeline 
This will fail my job

Comment: If you have bash there is quick and dirty solution. You probably know that but maybe it helps someone.
`cp *.jar *.war || true` It will not fail your pipeline. But it never fails...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this would work in `bash`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

jar_files=( directory/*.jar )
war_files=( directory/*.war )

if [[ ${#jar_files[@]} -eq 0 && ${#war_files[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    cp "${war_files[@]}" destination/
elif [[ ${#jar_files[@]} -gt 0 && ${#war_files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    cp "${jar_files[@]}" destination/
elif [[ ${#jar_files[@]} -gt 0 && ${#war_files[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Both jar and war files present; not copying anything."
else
    echo "No jar or war files found!"
fi
```

Save the jar and war files in respective arrays, and then see if they have 0 elements or not and copy the other if so.